# MYSQL: Update columnA to 1, if columnB = $value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update columnA in my database, if columnB is = $value.

```
$value = $_GET["value"];

UPDATE table WHERE columnA = '$value' SET columnB = '1';
```

It is not working, and if I would get it to work, how would the system know that it should only update that specific row? And not the entire columnB rows?

Comment: MySQL docs would have showed this SO is supposed to be a last resort not a first point of call: https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=mysql%20where%20update the first result is the answer you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write `SET` clause and then `WHERE` caluse like

```
UPDATE table_name SET columnB = '1' WHERE columnA = '$date' ;
```

Comment: Ok...when I add this to my web service, nothing shows up in my browser. Am I missing something?

Comment: I can see different stuff from my database in my web service, and when I add this to the php file, the browser shows nothing...

Comment: Thank you for the help! Much obliged! I had some minor typos...once I corrected it, everything worked out :)